# Laravel with(): What this method does?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I am new on Laravel and working on small application. In Laravel tutorials, I have read the **with()** method of Eloquent model but not able to understand it's working clearly.

I have seen many tutorials to clear this concept. Somebody post small understanding and somebody post deep understanding of **with()** method. At one place someone trying to clear this below example:

```
$collection = Model_1::where("year", 2016)->with(array("Model_2"=>function($q){$q->with("Model_3","Model_4");}))->with("Model_5","Model_6")->get()->toArray();
```

Overall, still I am not able to understand the concept of this method. Please anyone can clear me the concept of with() method and explain the working of above statement? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply. Can you please explaing the working of given query statement. Mat be this clearification can clear my doubts?

Answer (score 2):

Method `with()` on Eloquent model enables for you eager loading.

That means, when you do request on some model, you could do other requests to the database, if you need this data. Eloquent will fill out you model with loaded data.

If you do not include some related models to your model and will request them after, Eloquent will apply the new request to DB.

You could read more about eager loading in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Answer (score 0):

This basically does 6 separate queries.

It will start with a fetch all for year 2016:

```
select * from [Model_1_table] where `year` = 2016;
```

Then, it will do a new query which is constrained by the result of the query and the relation between `Model_1` and `Model_2`, then it will do the same for `Model_3` and `Model_4`, in relation to the fetched `Model_2`'s.

After that it will perform 2 other queries to eager load `Model_5` and `Model_6` based on the relation defined between those and `Model_1` and the query where clause.

Finally it merges it all together in 1 big happy array.

---

This would basically be the same as writing:

```
$array = Model_1::where("year", 2016)
    ->with('Model_2.Model_3', 'Model_2.Model_4', 'Model_5', 'Model_6')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

Answer (score -2):

This `with()` method is used from a certain model which is specified inside this method.

For example, if you have model called 'Country' and method called 'city', you would write `Country::with('city')` inside your controller or wherever you want.

Shortly, it enables you to use method of a model.

Comment: That's totally wrong, all methods will be always enabled on your model, but with `with()` method related models will be pre-loaded with eager loading