# what's the With() method in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I had refer some online references for understanding what to do with With method in laravel but still not understand.
[Laravel with(): What this method does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42359572/laravel-with-what-this-method-does)

Here are some codes which I'm not understand, may I know what the a,b,c,d,e,f refer to?

```
 $example = Test::with('a', 'b', 'c',
            'd', 'e', 'f');
```

Comment: It's eager-loading relationships to reduce database calls - https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: @aynber then the param inside with method refer to what?

Comment: Each parameter is a relation defined in the Test model.

Comment: ya, and inside the test model there are some methods there, may i know what is refer to and what use?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let me give you a direct example. If you've **user** table and that user table can be related to multiple tables right?? and it is also belongs to multiple tables?.

> Here, I have take four tables.

**city**

1. id
2. name

**User**

1. id
2. name
3. city_id

**user_profile**

1. id
2. user_id
3. address
4. phone

**user_documents**

1. id
2. user_id
3. document_name
4. type

---

> User `belongsTo` one city,
>
> User `has one` profile
>
> User `has many` documents.

Now, In the User model, you can define the relationship as below.

**User.php**

```
//User belongs To City
public function city(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\City','city_id','id')->withDefault();
}


//User hasone profile
public function profile(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile','user_id','id')->withDefault();
}

//User hasmany document
public function documents(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserDocument','user_id','id')->withDefault();
}
```

Now if you want to access this all data in the controller then you can get it by using **with()**

**Controller**

```
App\User::with('city','profile','documents')->get();
```

you'll get all data in object as

---

**User**

id

name

- {city data}
- {profile}
- {documents}

---

In addition, You can get multiple model nested relationship as well, Like city belongs to state and if you want to get state data with  city then,

```
User::with('city.state','profile','documents')->get(): 
//define state relationship in city model you'll get state data with the city as well.
```

> You can also add condition in `with()`

```
User::with(['document'=>function ($q){
    $q->where('type','pdf');
}]);
```

Comment: Can you help me with this? thx
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507929/how-can-i-get-data-from-database-without-using-db-query?noredirect=1#comment101483722_57507929