# Laravel-Vue3 - How to get Laravel relation data in vue.js component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have an application that originally built with laravel. Now I'm converting it to a Laravel-vue application.

I have a horse model which has a one-to-many relationship with a horseMedia model.

In my blade view I was getting the horse_midia like this

```
$horse->media_files
```

but now that I'm using vue components instead of blade, I'm trying to get the medida_files
like this:

```
horse.media_files
```

I'm expecting an object but this give me nothing

Comment: Use "with" to eager-load relationships. They are lazy-loaded usually. [what's the With() method in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498767/whats-the-with-method-in-laravel)

Comment: Your blade template perform another query to pull that `media_files` which you cannot do in a front-end with JS framework, you need to load the  `media_files` when you query the `$horse`. (before pusing the json back to the front-end)

Comment: I used with to eager load media files and it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ horse.media_files }}
```

You can get your output with this line , if you loaded your relation form back-end.